# Navigation Recovery Behaviors Criteria

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this page http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base it is explained how the recovery behaviors are activated.

I would like to know which are the criteria that activate any of the recovery behaviors included in the recovery_behaviors.yaml file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37537/navigation-recovery-behaviors-criteria/) by [Ricardo Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/589/ricardo-tellez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2012-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These recovery behaviors are activated whenever the move_base node decides that the robot is stuck. It is a good exercise to read the code for this, as any documentation (like this answer) can get outdated.

In this case you need to check the file:
navigation/move_base/src/move_base.cpp
E.g. here:
http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/unstable/api/move_base/html/move__base_8cpp_source.html

In there, search for any line like this:
state_ = CLEARING;

You will see that move_base will invoke these behaviors on three conditions: An oscillation was discovered, no global plan was received for some amount of time, or the local planner failed to find a valid velocity command for some amount of time.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4